# Moving the window does not work correctly

Tags: qt, qml

The problem is that the coordinates of the window are not set correctly. Therefore, the window is moved incorrectly and errors appear:

QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 400x400+62998+32284 on QQuickApplicationWindow_QML_0/''...

I don't know how to fix this. Here's the code:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    title: qsTr('Frameless')
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: 40
        color: "gold"

        anchors.top: parent.top

        Text {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            leftPadding: 8
            text: window.title
            color: "white"
        }

        MouseArea {
          anchors.fill: parent

          property real lastMouseX: 0
          property real lastMouseY: 0

          onPressed: {
             lastMouseX = mouse.x
             lastMouseY = mouse.y
          }
          onMouseXChanged: window.x += (mouse.x - lastMouseX)
          onMouseYChanged: window.y += (mouse.y- lastMouseY)
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: You should read the documentation more carefully. The parameter of MouseArea.MouseArea is [mouse](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#pressed-signal). There is no `mouseX` or `mouseY` and so you store some random values. Also note that `mouse.x` is real and so you lose precision while storing it in `int`. Another recommendation is to use debugger, it allows to solve such problems in moment.

Comment: I fixed my code a bit, but still, the effect remained. Maybe you know a working solution? I can't figure it out.

Comment: There is no item with id `mainWindow`, the `ApplicationWindow.visible` is false by default, you have to set it to true explicitly. It looks like you provide a code different from one you test and there are some other factors that affect the window position. With fixed code that works for me well.

Comment: I have two files in my project: main.cpp and main.qml. I added them. And still doesn't work for me.

Comment: `window.x += (mouse.x - lastMouseX)` this is always incremental and will grow indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you manage to solve this using QML you will see that the window will move with a LOT of jitter. It's mainly because of how bindings work (asynchronously). A better approach is asking C++ for `QCursor::pos()`
Here's a brief way on how to do that:
In your `main.qml` create a `MouseArea`:

```
MouseArea {
    property var clickPos
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPressed: {
        clickPos = { x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y }
    }
    onPositionChanged: {
        window.x = cpp_helper_class.cursorPos().x - clickPos.x
        window.y = cpp_helper_class.cursorPos().y - clickPos.y
    }
}
```

In your c++ cpp_helper_class you should have the following method:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QPointF cursorPos() { return QCursor::pos(); }
```

The `Q_INVOKALBE` makes sure your C++ code is accessible from QML.
Also your `main.cpp` should contain the following:

```
context->setContextProperty("cpp_helper_class", &helper_class_instance);
```